# WCF Transaction - TransactionScopeRequired = a hammer when we want tweezers?

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions

So in WCF to flow transactions from client to server you must have your

```
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
```

On your instance methods and

```
        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
```

On your service interfaces.  And everything works.  However, I find it concerning that
the server allocates a TX even if the client isn't flowing one up.  It seems wasteful

I understand .NET transactions can be lightweight.  Am I overreacting?  Should I just
trust in .NET and let it allocate a needless local transaction?  I'm worried it's 
unnecessary bulk, and even more worried it may get promoted to MSDTC involvement

EDIT 1:

The operation at hand which makes this clumsy is:

1. insert on table A
2. insert on table B
3. read on table A
4. insert on table C

Operation 3, read MUST be marked up as above as transactionscoperequired.  Otherwise since TX is not flowed, read times out.  I find this a little weird, brute forcing a TX to exist for a read-only operation.  It implies I'll have to mark most of the WCF calls in the system with a TransactionScopeRequired=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction is a tiny .NET in-memory data structure. It is nothing. What's expensive are the resource enlistments. That said, you are going to have at least one such enlistment.

Transactions usually *help* with database throughput, especially with writes.

You probably want your method to execute under a transaction anyway because you want effects to be atomic and reads to be consistent. It doesn't matter whether the client requests a tran or not.

> and even more worried it may get promoted to MSDTC involvement

That's a valid concern. That said distributed transactions are best avoided because they are slow and they do not work at all with some HA strategies like mirroring and AG.

Comment: I basically agree.  However, there's a situation I'm encountering which makes it clumsy - my bad for not fully describing it before.  See edited original post

Comment: I'd love to avoid MSDTC but it seems like "the way" to do WCF client-server transacted code

Comment: @Malachi I suspect there is a way to accept flowed transactions and manually attach to them programmatically. There is no technical reason a WSDL could not advertise transaction support and have programmatic control at the same time. Alas, I don't know enough about this. I recommend you perform reads transactionally, though. If not, your reads happen under an unspecified isolation level. Might be SERIALIZABLE which you like don't want.